# How to do batch snapping in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I would like to perform snapping using Arcpy for a lot of files in all the lines of the shapefiles that don't connect to the nearest other lines, so they do.

I tried to do it in geopandas using Python but I can't make it work.

Since I don't know much about ArcPy I will show you what I have done in geopandas:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import snap
s=gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\ag_eus')
result=snap(s,s,0.5)
```

How this code would be converted in ArcPy?

I have done this process in regular Arcmap and worked great but how to do it in ArcPy so it can work with multiple shapefiles in a loop. If you can explain what you do too, would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snapping that you are looking for seems to be equivalent to the integrate tool. Beware of this tool because it modifies the input data. So you should make a copy of your fc first.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/geodatabase.gdb/" #define workspace (would be a directory if you have a set a shapefiles)
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(): #listfeature class create a python list with the names of all feature classes in the workspace
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, fc + "snapped") #copies each fc in a new fc with the name + "snapped. With shapefiles you would do fc[:-4] +"snapped.shp" as output name.
    arcpy.Integrate_management(fc + "snapped", 0.5)#or fc[:-4] +"snapped.shp" as output name for shapefile
```

Note that integrate is the "quick and dirty" snapping tool for ArcGIS. You could also select one of the Editing tools in the [editing toolbox](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/an-overview-of-the-editing-toolbox.htm) for more specific fixes (e.g. snap arcpy.Snap_edit() or extent), but those tools require at least a standard licence.

Comment: Can you also explain what are you doing because ArcPy documentation was no that helpful for me.For example where do you declare the shapefiles that you will use?

Comment: Is integrate suited for lines?

Comment: yes, but you can use snap if you want more rules and a focus on the last segments only.